# Python: writing from ftp to file, doesn't do newline

Tags: python, ftp

I'm trying to write a text file from an ftp site to a file on my machine, like so:

```
ftp = FTP(ftpName)
ftp.login()
ftp.cwd(filePath)
foo=open(myFile,"w")
ftp.retrlines("RETR stlint",foo.write)
ftp.close()
```

the file is writing successfully, but when I open my file, there are no newline characters. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

According to ftplib [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.retrlines) -

> FTP.retrlines(command[, callback])
>
> ... The callback function is called for each line with a string argument containing the line with the trailing CRLF stripped. The default callback prints the line to sys.stdout.

Perhaps you can create your own callback function that appends the newline when writing the line to file.

Example -

```
ftp = FTP(ftpName)
ftp.login()
ftp.cwd(filePath)
foo=open(myFile,"w")
def customWriter(line):
    foo.write(line + "\n")
ftp.retrlines("RETR stlint",customWriter)
ftp.close()
foo.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.retrlines) you will see that calling `retrlines` with the optional callback will strip the newlines at the end of each line first before calling the callback.

You could just create your own callback that appends a newline:

```
def append_newline(input):
    foo.write(input + "\n")
```

then use this with:

```
ftp.retrlines("RETR stlint", append_newline)
```